# IBM MQ JMS Message Listener

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I want to use javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory to connect to IBM MQ
Is it possible to specify the queue manager and channel manager while connecting ?

I want to avoid using com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory. I am using JBoss 4.3

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a .bindings file and use com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory for getting initialcontext and then go on normally like any jms queue ...

Check this link http://ibswings.blogspot.com/2008/02/integrating-mq-broker-6-with-bea.html

to see how to generate .bindings file using JMSAdmin.

slight change to the process described in the link, if mq is hosted on different machine:

InitCtx>  def qcf(com.bt.mq.QueueConnectionFactory) qmgr(queuemanager) host(ip) port(port) transport(client)

Comment: Hi
The link that you have provided tell me how to configure it with WebLogic, I want to know how to configure it with  JBoss, sorry for the incomplete question !!

Comment: Have you already tried the JBoss community wiki documenting this :

community.jboss.org/wiki/IntegrationWithWebSphereMQSeries